# Python: how to calculate removal effect correctly using Markov Chains

Tags: python, graph, markov-chains

I have a bunch of path-to-purchase chains, and the more I have, the more I'm getting stuck about building the graph and calculating the removal effect.

Let's imagine we have 5 different chains:

1. start -> facebook -> google -> remarketing -> conversion
2. start -> facebook -> google -> null
3. start -> facebook -> remarketing -> conversion
4. start -> google -> remarketing -> null
5. start -> facebook -> google -> facebook -> google -> conversion

I build the adjacency matrix using all possible pairs from these chains and I get here:

```py
['start', 'facebook', 'google', 'remarketing', 'conversion', 'null']
array([[0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Let's try to count **Removal effect** for `remarketing`: 1/5 * 1/5 = 1/25 ~ 0.04 (start -> google -> conversion)
Does it make any sense? It looks like these repeats make the adjacency matrix incorrect and result is also incorrect.

---

I understand how to do that without the 5th chain.
The adjacency matrix will be

```py
['start', 'facebook', 'google', 'remarketing', 'conversion', 'null']
array([[0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and  `remarketing` will be 0.
And **Removal effect** for `facebook`, for example, will be 1/4 * 2/3 * 2/3 ~ 0.11

---

So how to calculate **Removal Effect** correctly when you have lots of complicated chains?

Comment: It's perhaps more helpful to view transitions as probabilities, ie renormalise each row so that the sum of the elements on a row is always equal to 1; and view terminating states as "absorbing", ie add conversion->conversion and null->null in the matrix.